# Selecionar elemento com JQuery para adicionar uma tag

Tags: jquery

Quero adicionar linha cortando o texto com a tag `wrap('<strike>')` via JQuery. O problema é que preciso selecionar a tag P e SPAN que estão dentro da DIV class media-body, mas somente quando o checkbox que está dentro da DIV media-left estiver selecionado.

```
<div class="media">                         
<div class="media-left media-middle">
    <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox m-l-1">
        <input id="task" name="task" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" />
        <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
    </label>
</div>              
<div class="media-body">                
    <p class="notice-date">Data</p>         
    <span>Uma nota qualquer</span>                      
</div>
```

```
$('input[id="task"]:checked').each(function()   { 
$(this).closest('.notice-date').wrap('<strike>'); });
```

Tentei com alguns códigos como o acima e não tive sucesso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use este seletor:

```
$(this).closest('div').next('div').find("p, span").wrap('<strike>');
```

Irá pegar o `<p>` e `<span>` da `div` seguinte do `checkbox` selecionado e embrulhar na tag `<strike>`.

```js
$('input.task:checked').each(function(){ 
   $(this).closest('div').next('div').find("p, span").wrap('<strike>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="media">                         
   <div class="media-left media-middle">
      <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox m-l-1">
         <input class="task" checked name="task" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" />
         <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
      </label>
   </div>              
<div class="media-body">                
   <p class="notice-date">Data</p>         
   <span>Uma nota qualquer</span>                      
</div>       

<div class="media">                         
   <div class="media-left media-middle">
      <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox m-l-1">
         <input class="task" name="task" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" />
         <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
      </label>
   </div>              
<div class="media-body">                
   <p class="notice-date">Data</p>         
   <span>Uma nota qualquer</span>                      
</div>
```

> Importante lembrar que um id deve ser único na página. Portanto troquei os `ids` por `class`.

Comment: Valeu, só apliquei a mudança e resolveu..